# Unable to run test frameworks on mesos

Tags: java, python, c++, mesos

I installed apache mesos 0.24 like [here](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/). The master and the slave both run on a dedicated VM. I have started a master and a slave as a single node cluster. The problem is that I can't test the environment.When I try to run these commands:

```
# Run C++ framework (Exits after successfully running some tasks.).
$ ./src/test-framework --master=127.0.0.1:5050

# Run Java framework (Exits after successfully running some tasks.).
$ ./src/examples/java/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050

# Run Python framework (Exits after successfully running some tasks.).
$ ./src/examples/python/test-framework 127.0.0.1:5050
```

I get the following replies:

C++

```
-bash: ./src/test-framework: No such file or directory
```

JAVA

```
 Could not find or load main class TestFramework
```

Python

```
E1003 16:33:58.847239  7281 socket.hpp:174] Shutdown failed on fd=6: Transport endpoint is not connected [107]
```

During installation I did `make check`.

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The test framework for c++ is under

```
./build/src/test-framework
```

For python is under

```
./build/src/examples/python/test-framework
```

For java is under

```
./build/src/examples/java/test-framework
```

If you have already `cd build`, you could execute the command as the document directly : `./src/test-framework --master=127.0.0.1:5050`

Answer (score 2):

@Mitsos

Did you run `make check` before trying to run the test frameworks ?